# How to structure a Java generic class to accept a non-generic constructor argument

Tags: generics, types, constructor, inference

I'm writing a simple utility generic class that provides a constructor that takes a T[] argument.  I'd like to set up a second constructor that takes a String argument but uses the first constructor as part of the setup.

```
public class PermGenerator<T> {
    private final T[] values;
    public PermGenerator(T[] vals) {
        values = Arrays.copyOf(vals, vals.length);
    }
    public PermGenerator(String str) {
        this(str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new));
    }
```

I would expect the second constructor to map the String to an array of Characters and then invoke the first constructor.

Instead, the Java compiler complains that no suitable constructor can be found.

Can this be restructured to accomplish what I have in mind?
Thanks.

Here's one approach that might be acceptable.  Provide a static helper method to convert a String into a Character array.  Not as slick as C++, but it'll work:

```
    public static final Character[] asArray(String str) {
        return str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new);
    }
```

So, it would require the user to use the following syntax to construct the class:

```
    PermGenerator gen = new PermGenerator(PermGenerator.asArray("ACBC"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about providing a static helper method that directly creates an instance of the appropriate type?

```
public static final PermGenerator<Character> Create(String str) {
    return new PermGenerator(str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new));
}
```

Your users could then simply call:

```
PermGenerator gen = PermGenerator.Create("ABC");
```

(Depending on your preference and the API design conventions you are following in your library, you can of course use a more specific name than `Create`, such as `CreateFromString`.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already recognized the possibility in my latest update to the question.  I may go with that option if I have to, but I'm hoping for an approach which would be completely transparent to the user.

Comment: @user2626932: This answer is indeed based upon and meant to be an improvement over your latest update to the question.

Comment: I agree.  I didn't look closely enough at the posting and I apologize for that.  It is better than my proposed work-around.  I may adopt it, but I'll wait for a couple of days.